# Doubly Linked List C, insertion at specific position

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I could really use some help with an address book program I've been struggling on for days now. I'm working with a doubly linked list in C. I'm trying to add nodes into the list at user-entered positions, starting with position 0. The positions will not be entered out of range. (no inserts at position 1 before something at position 0 etc.) The positions can be repeated though: inserting the new node in the position before the previous position occupant. (for example: if position 1 has x, and new node is inserted at position 1 with y, position 1 now has y and position 2 has x)

I need to take the user entered position number and retrieve the current person in that position, but I can't quite get it right. Also, I have included my insert function if you wanted to take a look at that as well because it isn't working properly either. Thanks for any help!

EDIT: The main problem right now is that my code for finding pPersonCur is failing when position == 1. Also, the insert function is not entering things in the proper order (the newest insertion in a position does not displace the older insertion correctly). The broken pPersonCur code makes it hard to diagnose why exactly this is, however.

addressbook.h excerpt:

```
typedef struct person Person;
struct person {
    char lastName[255];
    char firstName[255];
    char email[255];
    char phoneNumber[255];
    Person *pNext;
    Person *pPrev;
};
```

addressbook.c excerpt:

```
#include "addressbook.h"

Person * InsertPerson(Person * pPersonCur) {
    Person * pPersonNew;

    /* data gathered for CreatePerson() function here */

    pPersonNew = CreatePerson(pLastName, pFirstName, pEmail, pPhoneNumber);

    if (pPersonCur)
    {
        pPersonNew->pNext = pPersonCur;
        pPersonNew->pPrev = pPersonCur->pPrev;
        pPersonCur->pPrev = pPersonNew;
        if (pPersonNew->pPrev)
            pPersonNew->pPrev->pNext = pPersonNew;
    } else
    {
        pPersonNew->pPrev = pFirst;
        pPersonNew->pNext = NULL;
        if (pFirst)
            pFirst->pNext = pPersonNew;
    }
    return (pPersonNew);
}
```

main.c excerpt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "addressbook.h"

Person *pFirst;    /* First name in list */

int main(void) {

        Person *pPersonCur = NULL;    /* current Person */ 
        int bDone = 0, position = 0, counter = 0;

        pFirst = NULL;

    printf("Ready\n");

    while (!bDone) {
        char input = getchar();
        switch (input) {
        case 'a':
            counter = 0;
            scanf("%d", &position);    /* Where desired position is entered */
            if (position == 0) {
                if (pFirst) {
                    if (pFirst->pNext) {
                        pPersonCur = pFirst->pNext;
                    }
                } else {
                    pPersonCur = pFirst;
                }
            } else {
                pPersonCur = pFirst->pNext;
                while (counter < position) {
                    pPersonCur = pPersonCur->pNext;
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            InsertPerson(pPersonCur);    /* Takes in person at desired position, return value is new inserted person */
            break;
        /* Some other cases here */
        case 'q':
            bDone = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
/* Rest of code */
```

Comment: That return value of `InsertPerson ` is there for a reason. You may want to make use of it.

Comment: That's not really a question...where is it going wrong? What "isn't quite right"?
I'd recommend you debug it and have a watch on the whole list and then you might see when it goes wrong and/or gets corrupted and, maybe, *in what manner* it is "going wrong"! 
Best of luck!

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeah I tried that as it was used in a similar problem, but I can't think up much use for it in this case considering I must enter the positions explicitly.

Comment: @noelicus Yeah that's true! I'll add more information to the post. The insert function is not entering things in the proper order (the newest insertion in a position does not displace the older insertion correctly. The main problem right now is that my code for finding pPersonCur is failing when position == 1.

Comment: Do you want to insert at a position relative to the last inserted element or something? Why don't you keep track of the head of the list and have the argument of `InsertPerson` be an `int`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems so that you never assign a value to `pFirst`.
When position is not `0` the line `pPersonCur = pFirst->pNext;` is executed and `pFirst` in this place is still `NULL`.

Add a condition to your insert function to check whether list's head is assigned.

```
Person * InsertPerson(Person * pPersonCur) {
    . . . 
    else
    {
        pPersonNew->pPrev = pFirst;
        pPersonNew->pNext = NULL;
        if (pFirst)
            pFirst->pNext = pPersonNew;
        else
            pFirst = pPersonNew; // If pFirst is not assigned, assign it to newly created person
    }
    return (pPersonNew);
}
```

Despite that, if you happen to call `InsertPerson` with `NULL` argument, your code would put new `Person` after the first one and cut the rest of the list off.

To put new `Person` to the end of the list when called with `NULL` you could use something like this in your `InsertPerson` function:

```
if(pFirst) {
    Person *last = pFirst;
    while(last->pNext != NULL) {
        last = last->pNext;
    }
    last->pNext = pPersonNew;
    pPersonNew->pPrev = last;
}
else
    pFirst = pPersonNew;
```

Insertion according to position index might fail as well if you give a position index that is higher than there are nodes in the list. Some sort of safety check should be added as well.

```
pPersonCur = pFirst->pNext;
while (counter < position && pPersonCur->pNext != NULL) { // If last node reached, stop the loop
    pPersonCur = pPersonCur->pNext;
    counter++;
}
```

This implementation would add new `Person` to the end of the list if position index is too high.